# Perl: Instantiate complex data structure with constants from subclass

Tags: perl, constants, subclass, instantiation

I have a base class that is instantiated with a complex data structure with a three-digit number of entries, all of them constants. A few of those constants are class-specific and should be instantiated with different constants. I am having trouble achieving this. It boils down to this:

tstbase.pm:

```
package tstbase;

my $THISCLASSCONSTANT = "baseconstant.2";
my %complexdatastructure = (
    "attribute.1" => "baseconstant.1",
    "attribute.2" => $THISCLASSCONSTANT,
);

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = { };
    bless ($self, $class);
    $self->_init( $THISCLASSCONSTANT );
    return $self;
};

sub _init {
    my $self = shift;
    $THISCLASSCONSTANT = shift;
    foreach (keys %complexdatastructure) {
        $self->{$_} = $complexdatastructure{$_};
    };
};
```

tstsubclass.pm:

```
package tstsubclass;

use parent "tstbase";
my $THISCLASSCONSTANT = "subclassconstant.2";

sub _init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->SUPER::_init( $THISCLASSCONSTANT );
};
```

tst.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use tstbase;
use tstsubclass;

my $baseobj = tstbase->new;
print "Testbase ".$baseobj->{"attribute.1"}." ".$baseobj->{"attribute.2"}."\n";

my $subobj = tstsubclass->new;
print "Testsubclass ".$subobj->{"attribute.1"}." ".$subobj->{"attribute.2"}."\n";
```

Right now the output is

```
Testbase baseconstant.1 baseconstant.2
Testsubclass baseconstant.1 baseconstant.2
```

whereas I want it to be

```
Testbase baseconstant.1 baseconstant.2
Testsubclass baseconstant.1 subclassconstant.2
```

Is that possible? I am happy to use

```
sub THISCLASSCONSTANT = { "subclassconstant.2" }
```

if it helps. tstsubclass shall not have any baseconstant values. 
Right now I instantiate the class with magic strings and do a search & replace. It works, but seems less elegant and performant.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have asked this question before ( [Perl: Using common constructor for base and subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324253) ) but have over-simplified the example, hence the response could only hint at a possible solution.

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: You never use `$THISCLASSCONSTANT`!

Comment: (And you're missing `my`, so you're accidentally clobbering the existing var with that name instead of creating a new one.)

Comment: The goal is to use 'new' without parameters and have the class do the instantiation solely depending on itself.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear that you never use the `$THISCLASSCONSTANT` *you pass to `_init`*. This has nothing to do with `new`.

Comment: I guess that's my problem - where should I pass what in order to achieve the desired output while avoiding to change tst.pl and avoiding to copy %complexdatastratucture over to tstsubclass

Comment: The problem is not the passing. The problem is that you forgot to use it! You never place the value in `$self`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to work with references in your `%complexdatastructure`.
But note that when doing this, `$THISCLASSCONSTANT` will be changed after the first call to `tstsubclass->new`.

```
package tstbase;

my $THISCLASSCONSTANT = "baseconstant.2";
my %complexdatastructure = (
    "attribute.1" => \ "baseconstant.1",
    "attribute.2" => \ $THISCLASSCONSTANT,
);

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = { };
    bless ($self, $class);
    $self->_init( $THISCLASSCONSTANT );
    return $self;
};

sub _init {
    my $self = shift;
    $THISCLASSCONSTANT = shift;
    foreach (keys %complexdatastructure) {
        $self->{$_} = ${$complexdatastructure{$_}};
    };
};
```

Now your output is the desired one, but if you alter the order of the new calls like this:

```
my $subobj = tstsubclass->new;
print "Testsubclass ".$subobj->{"attribute.1"}." ".$subobj->{"attribute.2"}."\n";

my $baseobj = tstbase->new;
print "Testbase ".$baseobj->{"attribute.1"}." ".$baseobj->{"attribute.2"}."\n";
```

You'll get:

```
Testsubclass baseconstant.1 subclassconstant.2
Testbase baseconstant.1 subclassconstant.2
```

What you could do now is to write your "own" little `local` (i don't know why the normal `local` isn't working even with altering the declarations of `$THISCLASSCONSTANT` to `our`)

change your `tstbase::_init` into:

```
sub _init {
    my $self = shift;
    my $oldconstant = $THISCLASSCONSTANT;
    $THISCLASSCONSTANT = shift;
    foreach (keys %complexdatastructure) {
        $self->{$_} = ${$complexdatastructure{$_}};
    };
    $THISCLASSCONSTANT = $oldconstant;
};
```

Now i think you have what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that definetly foes the trick. I added a little bit of code to the foreach loop so it works with both references and non-references which saves me from having to change all of the various %complexdatastructure-s in my modules:
        `if (ref($complexdatastructure{$_})) {`
            $self->{$_} = ${$complexdatastructure{$_}};
        }
        else {
            $self->{$_} = $complexdatastructure{$_};
        };`

Comment: If you like brefity, you also could do `$self->{$_} = ref $_ ? ${$complexdatastructure{$_}} : $complexdatastructure{$_};` in the loop (sorry if wrong, on my Phone).

Comment: I actually did that already - after years of using if-then-else I am giving the ternary operator another shot, and this was one of the pieces of code I have changed. I am not yet sure if it is more readable to me, but it sure is easier to type (especially on a phone ^^)